# python Disocrd guild.voice.channels.create_invite() is not running

Tags: python, discord.py

if I input !3people Job Offer I got this image's error. Please resolve my error.
My OS is windows 10 home and discord.py version is 1.0.1
Thank you.

```
if m.content.startswith('!') and 'Job Offer' in m.content:
    if m.content\[1\].isdigit()!=True or int(m.content\[1\]) > 3 or int(m.content\[1\]) <= 0:
        embed = discord.Embed(color=0x06afff)
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Squad", color=0x06afff)
        embed.add_field(name="warning", value="Please input correct value.", inline=False)
        await m.channel.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        comment = ''
        for i in m.guild.voice_channels:
            if m.author in i.members:
                embed = discord.Embed(title="Squad", color=0x06afff)
                print(i.create_invite())
                embed.add_field(name="Squad", value=(await i.create_invite()),  inline=False)
                print(i)
                embed.add_field(name="Title", value=i, inline=False)
                cnt=4-int(m.content\[1\])
                embed.add_field(name="user count", value='%d /4'%(cnt), inline=False)
                if 'Job Offer' in m.content:
                    comment = m.content.split('Job Offer')\[1\]
                if len(comment) == 0:
                    comment = 'Today's finish is chicken'
                embed.add_field(name="Comment", value=comment, inline=False)
        await m.channel.send(embed=embed)
    await m.channel.send('@here')
```

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxkxY.png)

Comment: As the error message clearly states, you need to `await` your `create_invite` call. You are doing that in the embed line already, but not in the print-line right before

Comment: In addition to @LukasThaler: Please also check the invites your bot made in the server settings. The error message says that you reached the maximum and first have to delete the ones the bot created if they are not temporary.

Answer (score 0):

`create_invite` is a coroutine so it needs to be `await`ed.

The simple fix is to edit line 12:

```py
print(await i.create_invite())
```

Adding the `await` before `i.create_invite()` should solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks to your advice. I'll try that.

Comment: I try Adding the await command before i.create_invite() function. but I got this Error.           in on_message
    print(await i.create_invite())                                                                                                  in create_invite
    data = await self._state.http.create_invite(self.id, reason=reason, **fields)

Comment: I need more of the error to figure out what the issue is.